# Google Places API with Location Bias returns single distant result

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I was using Google Maps API to aid in location searches but unexpectedly get a single distant result for very general searches. So I switched to use Google Places API because of `locationbias` but now Google Places seems to return only a single location and does not use location bias to narrow the location to the latitude and longitude radius given.

Example:

> Text Search = "123 Main St"
>   Circle Radius = 16000 meters (10 miles)
>   Lat/Long = 41.761898,-72.674596 (Hartford, Connecticut)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?inputtype=textquery&key=[KEY]&locationbias=circle:16000@41.761898,-72.674596&query=123+Main+St
```

Result:

> "123 Main St, San Francisco, California"

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "123 Main St, San Francisco, CA 94105, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
           "lat" : 37.7917688,
                   "lng" : -122.3944272
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.79301167989272,
                  "lng" : -122.3931579701073
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.79031202010728,
                  "lng" : -122.3958576298927
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
         "id" : "596b2040c5c04babad99f2c1adcba7e943324bbb",
         "name" : "123 Main St",
         "place_id" : "ChIJZRkIYGSAhYARyXebnnhvMC0",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "QJR4+P6 SoMa, San Francisco, CA, USA",
            "global_code" : "849VQJR4+P6"
         },
         "reference" : "ChIJZRkIYGSAhYARyXebnnhvMC0",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I would expect it to return either a single result (123 Main St, Hartford Connecticut) respecting the `locationbias`, or many results, starting with the closest to Hartford, Connecticut.

**So how can Google Places API be used with `locationbias` to return the expected result? Or how can I include some type of location bias to the Google Maps API.**

Comment: What about https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Comment: I've tested that out and it seems to work well. I noticed I may have confused which methods use parameters `locationbias` and which use `location` and `radius` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to put an answer to this (comment of OP is noted):

textquery accepts `location` and `radius`

The following query returns the desired address on the 2nd result :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?inputtype=textquery&key=API_KEY&location=41.761898,-72.674596&radius=16000&query=123+Main+St